# python regex sub not working due to escape sequence

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have this kind of text. -> Roberto is an insurance agent who sells two types of policies: a $$\$$50,000$$ policy and a $$\$$100,000$$ policy. Last month, his goal was to sell at least 57 insurance policies. While he did not meet his goal, the total value of the policies he sold was over $$\$$3,000,000$$. Which of the following systems of inequalities describes $$x$$, the possible number of $$\$$50,000$$ policies, and $$y$$, the possible number of $$\$$100,000$$ policies, that Roberto sold last month?

I want to replace expressions containing dollar signs such as  $$\$$50,000$$. Removing things such as $$y$$ worked out quite well, but the expressions that contain escape sequence doesn't work well.

This is the code I used.

```
re.sub("$$\$$.*?$$", "", text)
```

This didn't work, and I found out that \ is a escape str, so should be written as \. So I replaced the expression as below.

```
re.sub("$$\\$$.*?$$", "", text)
```

However, this again didn't work. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks a lot in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `$` is a regex metacharacter, and so will need to be escaped if intended to refer to a literal `$`:

```
text = """Roberto is an insurance agent who sells two types of policies: a $$\$$50,000$$ policy and a $$\$$100,000$$ policy. Last month, his goal was to sell at least 57 insurance policies. While he did not meet his goal, the total value of the policies he sold was over $$\$$3,000,000$$. Which of the following systems of inequalities describes $$x$$, the possible number of $$\$$50,000$$ policies, and $$y$$, the possible number of $$\$$100,000$$ policies, that Roberto sold last month?"""
output = re.sub(r'\$\$(?:\\\$\$)?.*?\$\$', '', text)
print(output)
```

The above pattern makes the `\$$` optional, to cover all cases.